# How to shift the eigenvalues of a quantum Hermitian operator G to ±r?

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider a gate $\mathcal{G}(\mu)=e^{-i \mu G}$ generated by a Hermitian operator G. If G has just two distinct eigenvalues(which can be repeated) we can, without loss of generality,
shift the eigenvalues to ±r, as the global phase is unobservable. Note that any single qubit gate is of this form.

I dont know **How to shift the eigenvalues of a quantum Hermitian operator G to ±r ?**

[Schuld, Maria, et al. "Evaluating analytic gradients on quantum hardware." Physical Review A 99.3 (2019): 032331.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11184)

Comment: The link is complete bogus; please review.

Comment: Do you mean: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.032331

Comment: sry, I have editted the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *G* has eigenvalues *a* and *b*,
$$
G-\frac{a+b}{2} {\mathbb I}
$$
will have eigenvalues $\pm \frac{a-b}{2}$. But adding the extra identity term to *G* merely adds a global phase  $-i\mu (a-b)/2$  to $\cal G$ ...